# Full-justification with a Java Graphics.drawString replacement?

Tags: java, graphics, text, 2d

Does anyone know of existing code that lets you draw fully justified text in Java2D?

For example, if I said, `drawString("sample text here", x, y, width)`, is there an existing library that could figure out how much of that text fits within the width, do some inter-character spacing to make the text look good, and automatically do basic word wrapping?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Although not the most elegant nor robust solution, here's an method that will take the [`Font`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) of the current [`Graphics`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) object and obtain its [`FontMetrics`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) in order to find out where to draw the text, and if necessary, move to a new line:

```
public void drawString(Graphics g, String s, int x, int y, int width)
{
    // FontMetrics gives us information about the width,
    // height, etc. of the current Graphics object's Font.
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();

    int lineHeight = fm.getHeight();

    int curX = x;
    int curY = y;

    String[] words = s.split(" ");

    for (String word : words)
    {
        // Find out thw width of the word.
        int wordWidth = fm.stringWidth(word + " ");

        // If text exceeds the width, then move to next line.
        if (curX + wordWidth >= x + width)
        {
            curY += lineHeight;
            curX = x;
        }

        g.drawString(word, curX, curY);

        // Move over to the right for next word.
        curX += wordWidth;
    }
}
```

This implementation will separate the given `String` into an array of `String` by using the [`split`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method with a space character as the only word separator, so it's probably not very robust. It also assumes that the word is followed by a space character and acts accordingly when moving the `curX` position.

I wouldn't recommend using this implementation if I were you, but probably the functions that are needed in order to make another implementation would still use the methods provided by the [`FontMetrics` class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html).

Comment: Thanks - I actually started working on a similar method, and there are a number of similarities in our approach.  I'm also adding some logic that can tweak the inter-character spacing.

Answer (score 1):

For word wrapping, you might be interested by [How to output a String on multiple lines using Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239537/how-to-output-a-string-on-multiple-lines-using-graphics). No justification here, not sure if it is easy (or impossible!) to add...