# How to Add Height element while Appending text on images

Tags: java, image, text, graphics, awt

I am Looking if we can add Height element in the given [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400566/full-justification-with-a-java-graphics-drawstring-replacement).

So that i can Specify

```
public void drawString(Graphics g, String s, int x, int y, int width,int height)
```

Now if my text is more than height it is overlapping on next text.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You want to draw string which occupies more than one line..?

Comment: I am drawing string which occupies more than one line. But i want to restrict String if last line crosses specified height.

Comment: One way is to use HTML formatting in a `JLabel` & set the desired width as a style.  See the [`LabelRenderTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5853992/418556) source for an example.  Once the width and string is set, the label should be able to report the preferred size (including height).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test that, but that might help you with your problem..

```
public void drawString(Graphics g, String s, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    // FontMetrics gives us information about the width,
    // height, etc. of the current Graphics object's Font.
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();

    int lineHeight = fm.getHeight();

    int curX = x;
    int curY = y;
    int totalHeight = 0;

    String[] words = s.split(" ");

    String word = "";
    // end of words array wasn't reached and still some space left
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length && totalHeight <= height; i++) {

        // Find out thw width of the word.
        int wordWidth = fm.stringWidth(word + " ");

        // If text exceeds the width, then move to next line.
        if (curX + wordWidth >= x + width) {
            curY += lineHeight;
            totalHeight += lineHeight;
            curX = x;
        }

        g.drawString(word, curX, curY);

        // Move over to the right for next word.
        curX += wordWidth;
    }
}
```