# Break String into paragraphs so I can print it in another class

Tags: java, printing

Okay, so I have a code which gets information from one class and sends it to print in another class after the action is performed.

This code gets the Strings that are in the `TextAreas` available and merges them in order to send them to the other class. This is the `ActionListener` which merges the `TextAreas` and opens another frame to confirm the printing action.

```
JButton button_2 = new JButton("Print  ");
    button_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String line= textArea.getText();
            String line2=textArea_1.getText();
            String line3=line+line2;
             Print.setLine(line3);
                contentPane.setVisible(false);
                dispose();
                Print p=new Print();
                p.setVisible(true); 
        }

    });
```

This is the class code. It receives the String which is supposed to be printed. The only problem is it should be printed into a paragraph, and it prints as a straight line (because it is a String)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


import java.awt.print.*;

public class Print implements Printable, ActionListener {
public static String line="";




public String getLine(){
    return line;
}
public static void setLine(String x){
    line=x;

}


public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws

PrinterException {

    if (page > 0) { 
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());   
    g.drawString(this.linea, 100, 100);
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
     job.setPrintable(this);
     boolean ok = job.printDialog();
     if (ok) {
         try {
              job.print();
         } catch (PrinterException ex) {

         }
     }
}

   public static void main(String args[]) {

}



public void setVisible(boolean b) {
    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Print");
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
       public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
    });
    JButton printButton = new JButton("Click to print");
    printButton.addActionListener(new Print());
    f.add("Center", printButton);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);


}



}
```

How do I break the long String into paragraphs? Would it be better if I generated a  Word document?

Comment: It will be better to generate a word document depending on how much data you are reading. Eclipse will eventually cut the data in the console since it doesn't have infinite amounts of memory. You will not be able to see the whole output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full-justification with a Java Graphics.drawString replacement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400566/full-justification-with-a-java-graphics-drawstring-replacement)

Comment: Why are you concatenating two strings, if your goal is to split them apart again?  If a single string from one text area can contain multiple paragraphs, surely there must be (at least) a paragraph break between two strings from two _separate_ text areas...  the user has already split them for you.