# JTextArea Printing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, drawstring

I have an JTextArea with some lines of text in it.I want to print that lines of text, here i am using the method getText() and storing the whole data into a string variable. I am passing that string to the print class. while printing that string, text is printed without any spaces, new line or tabs etc. can any one help me by solving my problem.

My printing code

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException 
    {


        if (page > 0) 
        {                                                                                           
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
        g.drawString(data,10,10);
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
```

Here data is my string variable.

thank u...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: Exactly what are you talking about with "printing"?  You talk about Strings, JTextArea, getText(), yet I see no mention or use of them in the code.  So exactly what is this print() method supposed to do?  Nobody knows.

Comment: thanks for ur quick reply.
k the only thing what i need is to print the data from text area as it is. so what should i do now.

thank u

Answer (score 1):

If your data variable has spaces it should be included when you draw the string.  However drawString does not handle new lines for you.

See this question about how to handle this:  [How to output a String on multiple lines using Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239537/how-to-output-a-string-on-multiple-lines-using-graphics)

Answer (score 0):

I would call it this way

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;         
g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());         
myTextArea.paint(g);
```